# Sed - Move/Insert text from the hold buffer

Tags: bash, sed

I'm brand new to sed.

I have

```
--
-- data_table
--
Insert Statement

More stuff

Last Line
```

I'd like to move the Insert Statement (with table comment above) to before the Last Line.

I have this to move it to the end:

```
sed '/-- data_table/,/Insert Statement/{H;d};$g' >> file.sql
```

Produces:

```
--

More stuff

Last Line

-- data_table
--
Insert Statement
```

and that works, what I'd like though is what I mentioned above. I tried to use this:

```
sed '/-- data_table/,/Insert Statement/{H;d};/Last Line/ig' >> file.sql
```

but that just puts in a 'g' before the last line and does nothing else. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, or can /i\ only be used with defined text after it?

Also on a less crucial note if anyone knows how I can also move the whole

```
--
-- data_table
--
```

instead of just the last 2 lines of it that would be great. I tried:

```
 sed '/--\n-- data_table/,/Insert Statement/{H;d};$g' >> file.sql
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/--/{:a;N;/data_table/!{P;D};/Insert Statement/!ba;h;d};/Last Line/{H;g}' file
```

Look for a comment line and if the next/or currrent line contains `data_table` continue gathering lines until `Insert Statement` then store these lines in the hold Space (HS) and delete these lines. On encountering `Last Line` append this line to the HS and the replace the current line with the contents of the HS.

N.B. If the comment line or following line does not contain `data_table` the first line is released and the process begins again. Also if there are more than one `Last Line` these will also be treated in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/-- data_table/,/Insert Statement/{H;d};/Last Line/ G' >> file.sql
```

- `i` is not for insert here but an option of `s///` taht mean case insensitive
- `g` is also an option of `s///` that mean 'every occurence'
- `G` (alone) is Append to buffer where `g` is replace the buffer

so you need to remove the `i`, separate the `g` form `s///`command and use the wanteg `g`/`G`.

be carefull if several /Last line/ and /data_table,/Insert/ are present, you certainaly not have the wanted result from second occurence to the end

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/--/,/Insert Statement/{H;d};/Last Line/{x;p;x}' >> file.sql
```

`{x;p;x}` does the following:

- Exchanges pattern space with hold buffer (Last Line goes to buffer, Insert Statement - to pattern space)
- Prints pattern space (Insert Statement)
- Exchanges pattern space with hold buffer again (Last Line goes to pattern space)

BTW, changing `-- data_table` to `--` solves the issue with matching the incomplete comment.